# Use yocto to extend a read-only filesystem with extra packages

Tags: yocto, openembedded

I have an embedded linux "proof-of-concept" project that wants to add some packages to an existing piece of hardware with a read-only filesystem.  I am very new (1 week) to Yocto but it seems like it is possible.  Looking for a general road map of how to achieve this, but any detailed strategy ideas would be helpful to keep in mind as I RTFYM.

- It is a networked device, running on ARMv5t hardware.
- 64GB SD/MMC card is available (empty) and mounted.
- telnet, nfs, busybox utils available.
- no resident dev tools

The packages I need to add are openssl, python, zeromq, pyzmq, and perhaps other python modules in the future.  I cannot place these into the rootfs because it is read-only, but they can reside on the sd card.  I am trying to understand how to use Yocto to create this set of packages and collect them together as a build output.  What I have so far:

- EXTERNAL_TOOLCHAIN and meta-sourcery recipe is working
- I can build python and pyzmq independently with bitbake -b
- Don't know how to add pyzmq or other modules to python tree
- How to build & collect just these items without building entire image?

The python part is running on the hardware but I just hand-copied it to the nfs folder.  I am asking if this is a valid approach and if so, to add some directional detail. I hope I have provided enough information.

Comment: "add pyzmq or other modules to python tree" -- what does this mean?

Comment: Okay, poor choice of the wording on my part.  By python tree I think what I mean is the modules within the site-packages folder.  Unfortunately now I have a different issue, I thought my external Code Sourcery arm-2009q1 toolchain was working because it can build python and pyzmq, but it fails when building the whole core-image-minimal machine for qemuarm.